# Two NICs with Ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: networking

I have two NICs within my Ubuntu server. One being the internet, the other being an internal network. I have the following configuration whereas eth0 is the internet, eth1 is the internal network

```
auto lo eth0 eth1
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.21
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Eth0 works correctly and I cannot connect via the internal IP. Both eth's are up. Thanks.

**EDIT: ** added the following line to /etc/network/interfaces

```
up route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1
```

Seems to have fixed it **but**, the connection is very intermittent.

**EDIT 2: ** After about 10 mins of everything working, I can no longer connect to the external IP address. I read somewhere that having two gateways can mess the networking up. Am I affected by this?

Comment: Hi James, what question are you asking?

Comment: Eth0 works correctly, but eth1 does not seem to be working. I.e. I can connect to the server via the external IP from the internet, but not the internal IP.

Comment: Have you checked the net config on the local client system?

Comment: Tried to connect with the internal IP address on 3 different computers.

Comment: Can you disconnect the external and post the IP you get from the internal. Then connect the external, disconnect the internal and s the IP of that one also.

Comment: Sorry Luis, I don't quite understand.

Comment: Hi James, I'm pretty sure I've just replied to your another question on the same issue (http://askubuntu.com/questions/289149/two-nics-ubuntu-server-12-04) - is there a reason for reposting it on the same site?